# Unable to perform PressBack in Espresso Test

Tags: android-espresso

In One espresso test,I am trying to click inside RecyclerView item using following code snippet.While clicking on item,It launches another ACTIVITY.
Afterwards if i perform **pressBack**,It stucks at that point.

```
@Test
public void performClickTest(){
        onView(withId(R.id.rv_endless_scroll))
           .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
           .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToHolder(ViewHolderViewMatcher()))
           .perform(RecyclerViewHolderActions());
}


public static class RecyclerViewHolderActions implements ViewAction {
        ViewAction click = click();

        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return click.getConstraints();
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
           TextView view = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_clickable);

           //on text item click,it Launches new activity (activityOne --> activityTwo)
           click.perform(uiController,view);

            /////////////// To come back on activityOne,pressBack is not working////
            //////////////// Test is getting stuck on below line//////// 
            pressBack();
        }
}
```

Is this correct way to perform click inside RecyclerView Item  and/or **PressBack** operation ?